# Despite the name of the file and the name of the class being the same, Unity still can't find the class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Despite the many times I have rewritten the file and made sure the class and the file name match up unity is still saying it can't find the script class. I even made sure all the spelling important words were correct, and it still says it can't find the script class. The name of the file is BasicAI.cs This is what the file looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    public class BasicAI : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;
        public ThirdPersonCharacteracter character;

        public enum State {
            PATROL,
            CHASE
        }

        public State state;
        private bool alive;

        //Patrolling
        public GameObject[] markers;
        private int markerID=0;
        public float patrolSpeed=0.0f;

        //Chasing
        public float chaseSpeed=1f;
        public GameObject target;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
            character = GetComponent<ThirdPersoncharacter>();

            agent.updatePosition = true;
            agent.updateRotation = false;

            state = BasicAI.State.PATROL;
            alive = true;

            StartCoroutine("FiniteState");
        }

        IEnumerator FiniteState()
        {
            while(alive)
            {
                switch(state)
                {
                    case State.PATROL:
                        Patrol();
                        break;
                    case State.CHASE:
                        Chase();
                        break;
                }
                yield return null;
            }

        }

        void Patrol()
        {
            agent.speed = patrolSpeed;

            if(Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, markers[markerID].transform.position) >= 2)
            {
                agent.setDestionation(markers[markerID].transform.position);
                character.move(agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
            }
            else if(Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, markers[markerID].transform.position) <= 2)
            {
                markerID += 1;
                if(markerID>markers.Length)
                {
                    markerID = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                character.move(Vector3.zero, false, false);
            }

        }

        void Chase()
        {
            agent.speed = chaseSpeed;
            agent.setDestionation(target.transform.position);
            character.move(agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
        }


        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Player")
            {
                    state = basicAI.State.CHASE;
                    target = other.GameObject;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting Unity?

Comment: Yes I have, twice.

Comment: Have you tried without the namespace? Where is the script located in reference to the Assets directory?

Comment: in asset directory I always keep all assets in the same folder, so all scripts are kept in a folder called scripts

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Can't add script component 'BasicAI' because the script class cannot be found. the console says nothing about that file

Comment: "basicAI" in the last but one line is lowercase, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes even with that it doesn't solve the problem.I tried.

Comment: Any other script errors in other files? Will VS compile the project? (Yes, I realise this is for Unity)

Comment: Yes, but it's a script that controls menu UI.